# Can't get MongoDB to work with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have Fedora 13, and I have installed httpd, php, and mysql using yum.

Then downloaded mongodb.

Added the `extension=mongo.so` to my php.ini

Restarted httpd

Wrote the following code:

```
<?php
$connect = new mongo();
$db = $connect->data;
$collection = $db->foobar;

$info = array("name" => "wael", "age" => 24);

$collection = insert($info);

$obj = $collection->findOne();
var_dump($obj);
?>
```

Tried running it.

But it shows nothing on my localhost.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you seeing anything in your error logs? This is going to be a bit hard to diagnose without some more info.

Comment: put `error_reporting(-1)` on top of the script and make sure [`display_errors`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is enabled

Answer (score 1):

Let php report errors to you.
see [error_reporting](http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.error-reporting), [display_startup_errors](http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.display-startup-errors), [display_errors](http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.display-errors), [error_log](http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.error-log).
You might also want to check whether the extension has been loaded at all.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if ( !class_exists('mongo') ) {
  echo 'there is no class "mongo".   mongodb extension loaded: ';
  var_dump(extension_loaded('mongo'));
  echo 'php.ini used by this instance of php: ', get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
  die;
}


$connect = new mongo();
$db = $connect->data;
$collection = $db->foobar;
$info = array("name" => "wael", "age" => 24);
$collection = insert($info);
$obj = $collection->findOne();
var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: got it to work, i had to uninstall everything, re-add the repo, update yum which is the thing that fixed the problem.
and reinstalled. and it works fine now :)